# Google Calendar API not working with curl client request

Tags: json, curl, google-calendar-api

I am trying to create a google calendar event using curl this is my request but it is not working I have not idea what is the mistake that I am making :

> curl "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{CalID}/events?access_token={access_token}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{ "end": { "start": { "date": "2012-08-01", "dateTime": "2012-08-01 22:47:31.893205", "timeZone": "Asia/Calcutta" }, "end": { "date": "2012-08-08", "dateTime": "2012-08-08 22:47:31.893205", "timeZone": "Asia/Calcutta" }, "attendees": [ { "email": "dosi@iitpzx.com" }, { "email": "test@gmail.com" } ], "reminders": { "overrides": [ {  "method": "email", "minutes": 10 } ]  }  }'  -v

I keep getting Bad request Error.
Can some tell me what is wrong with this request..??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally got the correct request :

> curl
>   "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{CalendarID}/events?access_token={Access_token}"
>   -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d ' { "start": { "dateTime": "2012-07-11T12:47:31+05:30" }, "end": { "dateTime":
>   "2012-07-11T22:47:31+05:30" }, "attendees": [ { "email":
>   "{Attendee_Email}" } ], "reminders": { "overrides":[ ]  }  }'  -v

Comment: UPDATED cURL : 

curl --location --request DELETE 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{YOUR EMAIL}/events/{EVENT ID}' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {access_token}'

Comment: {
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Insufficient Permission",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
            }
        ],
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
    }
}